# How to display an image immediately after selecting it with ng2-file-upload?

Tags: angular

I am building a site with angular2 and using the ng2-file-upload library [ng2-file-upload](http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/)
I want to display an image on my site right after selecting it. How is this possible with this library?

Answer (score 5):

You can listen for `onAfterAddingFile` event and create the url for the local blob:

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({url: '/your/url' });
this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
    let url = (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file) : (window as any).webkitURL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file);
    this.localImageUrl = url
}
```

Now the img src you have to use is stored in `this.localImageUrl`. The problem is that when you try to use that in the DOM, Angular will mark it as unsafe. To overcome that, you need to import `DomSanitizer`:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

And inject it into your component's constructor:

```
export class MyComponent {
    (...)
    constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    (...)
    }
```

Finally, where you add the img in your template, use the sanitizer to trust the url:

```
<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(localImageUrl)">
```

Comment: Using `private sanitizer:DomSanitizer` in the constructor does not expose the sanitizer variable to the page. Should be `public sanitizer:DomSanitizer`

Comment: it does preview the image but then the angular app reload is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

follow the following simple solution

```
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    ...
    public previewPath: any;
    ....
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
       this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
          this.previewPath = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file)));
        }
    }
```

In html

```
 <img [src]="previewPath " alt="Avatar" class="contribution-image">
```